# Docking/Displaying Mutiple DataGridViews with Splitters Programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, runtime

All, I want to build and display multiple `DataGridView` seperated by horizontol `Splitter`s at runtime. To test out doing this I have created a test application with the following code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 1;
    List<DataGridView> DgvList = new List<DataGridView>() 
                                 { 
                                     new DataGridView(), new DataGridView() 
                                 };
    foreach (DataGridView Dgv in DgvList)
    {
        Dgv.Parent = this.panelMain;
        int verticalSize = (int)(panelMain.Height / DgvList.Count);
        Dgv.Height = verticalSize;
        Dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        if (DgvList.Count > 1 && i < DgvList.Count)
        {
            Splitter tmpSplitter = new Splitter();
            tmpSplitter.Parent = this.panelMain;
            tmpSplitter.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            tmpSplitter.BringToFront();
            tmpSplitter.Height = 8;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

However, this is not displaying the `Splitter`

[image: MultipleDgvs]

Can someone highlight the error of my ways?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop this line:

```
 tmpSplitter.BringToFront();
```

and splitter will show.

Note that you are displaying grids in reversed order - the first in list will be at bottom of the screen.